# Why ListTile does not default spash when clicked?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've populated my Drawer with a `ListTile` but when is clicked it doesn't do the default splash ripple.

here the code:

```
class ItemMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool show;
  final IconData icon;
  final String text;
  final Function onTap;

  ItemMenu(this.show, this.icon, this.text, this.onTap);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      onTap: onTap,
      title: Text(text,
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black)),
      leading: Icon(
        icon,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

code where I call `ItemMenu`: [pastebin.com/t1MZj6ZM](http://pastebin.com/t1MZj6ZM)

my theme isn't set to Colors.transparent. I've also tried to wrap into a `Inkwell` but nothing. What could be another reason?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: To work `InkWell` must be wrapped in `Material` widget.

Comment: But shouldn't ListTile  already have a default spash effect? because it does not work?

Comment: and besides I tried to wrap it in a Material but it doesn't work anyway

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap the list on inkwell to have the splash effect

Answer (score 0):

Changing the following line:

```
onTap: onTap,
```

to:

```
onTap: () => onTap(),
```

Seems to work on my end:

[image]

Sample working code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
    home: MyHomePage(),
  );
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)=> Material(
    child: Center(
      child:ItemMenu(
        true, Icons.edit, "Test", (){ print("hello"); }
      ),
    ),
  );
}


class ItemMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool show;
  final IconData icon;
  final String text;
  final Function onTap;

  ItemMenu(this.show, this.icon, this.text, this.onTap);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      onTap: () => onTap(),
      title: Text(text,
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black)),
      leading: Icon(
        icon,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  I tried but nothing change , I didn't obtain the splash effect when I click on it

Comment: here there is the code where I call it if you want to check https://pastebin.com/t1MZj6ZM

Comment: Try to remove the parent `Container()` of `SingleChildScrollView()` of the `ItemMenu`

Comment: I've tried before and I tried again now but no splash is seen